# How to add multitext values seperated by commas to optionset and lookup field in cm 2015 using c# plug-in

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a plug-in. This plug-in should get the values seperated by commas from multitext field one by one and stores to an optionset field.
And also this plugin should get values(ids) from multitext field seperated by comma and searches the ids one by one in lookup field values. If found (the search operation should be done one by one in a loop;since there will be more thean one id to search), the value should be seen in the lookup field. 
After theese opertaions the plugin should save the entity.

How can i do this in crm 2015 using c# visual studio plug-in? Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 1):

So, in a nutshell, what do you want to do is to generate the CRM metadata dynamically from a comma separated input, like a CSV?

Have a look at the [CreateOptionSetRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createoptionsetrequest(v=crm.6).aspx)  and [InsertOptionSetValueRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.insertoptionvaluerequest.aspx) in CRM, this will allow you to insert new option set values for a given option set.

Those will allow you to dynamically create an option set field, and populate option set values for that field, respectively.

For lookups, If I understood correctly, you can link records to each other using AssociateRequest messages.

Hope this helps

Comment: For lookup field will do according to the success of the service.Cerate(entity); procerss.

Comment: I have mutlline textbox field. It has more than one isd of firms. According to my scenario if the new_firm (lookkup filed) is empty; in my plug in i set the id from multitext box field to new_firm lookup field and save